# Nginx is working but : nginx.service: Can't open PID file on debian 10

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx 1.20.1 on Debian 10, it's working but on command `systemctl status nginx` this is shown:

> systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
> systemd[1]: nginx.service: Can't open PID file /run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or d
> systemd[1]: Started nginx - high performance web server.

I googled alot and checked permission of  related folders of address `/var/usr/nginx.pid` and checked the address to be the same in both `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` , and good to say that `nginx.pid` is created when nginx is running and it is deleted when I stop nginx. I tried using `/usr/nginx.pid` in .conf and .service but the same problem exists. In my error.log, no error or warning is logged. Also should mention that it's a fresh VM machine|debian and a fresh nginx! With no extra modification to default nginx.conf !

Question: should I have notice `Can't open PID file /run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or d` ? If it is important how could I resolve it?

Comment: Why did you change the PID file location?

Comment: ehm, /run exists on debian, have you deleted it? however, don't change things that you don't understand

Comment: I encountered the message `Can't open PID file`  on fresh nginx, with no config and default  settings, so I started to modify things ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed Number of CPUs of my virtual machine form `1` to `more than 1`, the problem solved (more than 2 days engaging). It was not a problem !! it was just a message on the screen 'Can't open PID file`  and nothing in the log file  and nginx working truely! But this message maybe is a bug according to this refrence :
[bugs.launchpad.ne](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864)